# How can I emit event from vue plugin to vue main app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say that I have a simple Vue plugin:

plugin.js

```
export default {
  install(Vue) {
    if (this.installed) {
      return;
    }

    this.installed = true;

    Vue.prototype.$myPlugin = {
      newEvent: () => {
        this.$emit('new-event-from-plugin'); // <-- does not work :(
      }
    };
  }
}
```

and I want to use it on my main Vue app:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>My app</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',

  created() {
    this.$on('new-event-from-plugin', () => {
      console.log('is it working?');
    });
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$myPlugin.newEvent();
  }
}
</script>
```

Assuming that I have registered the plugin correctly, **how can I emit an event from the plugin and listen to it on the main app?**

I've also tried to use:
`Vue.prototype.$emit();`
`Vue.$root.$emit();`

Comment: Can you try: 
`Vue.prototype.newEvent = function () {
        this.$emit('new-event-from-plugin');
    };`
?

Comment: @Anatoly It works! But, can't I use it with the function inside the object?

Comment: Try but do not use an arrow function to define newEvent

Comment: Still not working

Comment: try to convert an object to a function that returns functions binded to 'this'

Comment: Don't know how to do this, could you please show an example?

Comment: `Vue.prototype.$myPlugin = function () {
      return {
         newEvent: function () {
        this.$emit('new-event-from-plugin');
      }.bind(this)
    };`

and then use it like this.$myPlugin().newEvent()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Vue.prototype.$myPlugin = function () {  
  return { 
    newEvent: function () { 
     this.$emit('new-event-from-plugin'); 
    }.bind(this) 
  };
```

and then use it like

```
this.$myPlugin().newEvent()
```

Comment: I'm trying this method, and needing to call the function to emit from within my plugin (not separate Vue component with `this.$myPlugin().newEvent()`) so I'm trying 
`Vue.prototype.$myPlugin().newEvent()` where my event is `this.$emit('test')` I get `Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

in Vuejs we use the `$emit()` event when we want to emit a specific value with an event and listening to the event in **the parent component**. actually we play with `$emit()` in **vue components** and you want to emit an event from plugin.js!

I recommend you to use [pubsub.js](https://sahadar.github.io/pubsub/). this is useful and amazing library to provide your custom listeners.

you can use that like this:

```js
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';

export default {
  install(Vue) {
    if (this.installed) {
      return;
    }

    this.installed = true;
    
    PubSub.publish('new-event-from-plugin');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

```js
<template>
  <div>My app</div>
</template>

<script>
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';

export default {
  name: 'app',

  created() {
    PubSub.subscribe('new-event-from-plugin', () => {
      console.log("it's worked!");
    });
  }
}
</script>
```